# Brightness in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, laptop, brightness

Well this is a common problem as i have seen through my google searches but i didn't manage to find any satisfactory solution so far. I got my laptop recently which came with windows 8 pre-installed.I decided to install ubuntu (i had it in my former laptop) but the main problem is that when ubuntu starts the brightness is 0 be default(my laptop has a backlit button too). I can use the Fn buttons to change back to what i want but i wondered if there is a solution after all. The only solutions i found so far set the brightness in a default value which fix the low brightness problem after the start up but i cant control the brightness with the fn buttons afterwards. If anyone has a solution please share. Thanks in advance.
ps my laptop is Lenovo G510

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this might be a workaround

Edit you rc.local file which will run on each startup,

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

to write there something like,

```
echo 100 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

or

```
echo 100 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

depending on what defines your system brightness.

you can find out which brightness value is best for you by looking in the "actual_brightness" file. Then change the 100 for that number.

Comment: Your welcome. Please help me back and accept my answer. It is the button under the vote up and down arrows ;)

Comment: For my G510 I needed echo 3000 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness. The original value was 5273. I'm running 12.04 LTS btw