# Screen brightness in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, brightness, backlight

So at first even the brightness key (via <kbd>Fn</kbd> button) used to work in Ubuntu 18.04. After an update, i can't even change it from the setting. And with the keys, it just show the icon of the screen brightness which is changing, and doesn't actually do anything.

To be mentioned, with `brightness-controller-simple` which is suggested in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762764/cant-change-brightness-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts) answer, the "actual" brightness doesn't change, it just makes the colors more dark, with same amount of light coming out of the screen.
The `xbacklight` also doesn't work; I mean, this command doesn't do a thing `xbacklight -inc 10`, which is suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/754459/cant-change-brightness/754464).

I finally could change the actual brightness, but from the terminal command which i read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428467/brightness-in-ubuntu-12-04). Which is this command:

```
sudo bash -c "echo 130 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness;"
```

Is there any other way i could probably change the brightness?

---

I have ASUS model V502U. And results from `lspci -v | less`, video adapter part:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
Memory at dd000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: It would be constructive to click on the `edit` link above and to the left, and note the make and model of your laptop or all-in-one machine. Please get the model number from the serial number plate, not the top of front of the PC, as the model number from the serial number plate is much more helpful. Also, please run `lspci -v | less` and also paste the video adapter information into the original post.

Comment: @K7AAY Should i post the whole results from `lspci -v | less`?

Comment: The video adapter information only.

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer, but not the best one!

Read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871298/unable-to-change-brightness-in-settings/871579#871579), to change the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file.

I did the solution from that post, and installed the new updates, then  `xbacklight` worked. But still, I couldn't change the brightness from setting. According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/754459/cant-change-brightness/754464#754464) answer, you can increase the screen brightness by 10% by this command:

```
xbacklight -inc 10
```

And decrease the brightness by 10% by this command:

```
xbacklight -dec 10
```

Then create a keyboard shortcut, for intsance, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f9</kbd> for command `xbacklight -inc 10`, or so. Unfortunately, it doesn't let you use <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f9</kbd> shortcut, since it is supposed to have a job itself primitively.

Comment: `$ sudo apt install xbacklight`

This works very well.  I created the following custom hotkeys:
    `<Super><F4> for xbacklight -set 5  # Set to a reasonable lowest`
    `<Super><F5> for xbacklight -set 100  # Set to a highest`

Comment: 'not the best one' - gets best rate

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04 (with xfce desktop) my brightness problem finally solved.

I opened 'Onboard Settings' under the 'Settings' menu. If your desktop doesn't have one, you can download it from Software Center.

On the 'Onboard Preferences' window, click the Layout menu, then choose the 'Full Keyboard' (Desktop keyboard with edit and function keys). Click here to view the [Onboard Settings window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E7j8.png)

Answer (score 1):

In case the above suggestion doesn't help you. Here I am suggesting which might help you. I have installed fresh Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and landed at this problem. In case, you have Nvidia Graphics Driver. Please do the following:
Edit (or create) inside /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf

```
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
    Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1;" # Add this if it exists
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg"
EndSection
```

Commands:

```
sudo vim /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf
Check with the above code.
```

Answer (score 0):

We require "xrandr" command to view and set the screen on Ubuntu 18.

> root@joe-UBTPC:/home/jarurote# xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1600 x 900, maximum 32767 x 32767

**eDP1** connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 440mm x 250mm
   1600x900      60.00*+  59.82
   1440x900      59.89
   1400x900      59.96    59.88
   1368x768      60.00    59.88    59.85
   1360x768      59.80    59.96
   1280x800      59.81    59.91
   1152x864      60.00
   1280x720      59.86    60.00    59.74
   1024x768      60.00
   1024x576      60.00    59.90    59.82
   960x540       60.00    59.63    59.82
   800x600       60.32    56.25
   864x486       60.00    59.92    59.57
   800x450       60.00
   640x480       59.94
   720x405       59.51    60.00    58.99
   640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00

**VGA1** disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

**VIRTUAL1** disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

root@joe-UBTPC:/home/jarurote#

...

...

See that the 3rd line of output command shows the output screen of "**eDP1**".

To adjust the brightness of the screen, we can define the brightness of the screen in a range of [0.3, 1.0].  Suppose we need the brightness of 0.4, the command of xrandr should be like this.

> xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness .4

That is it.

**PS:**  Don't adjust the brightness value higher than 1.

Comment: This does not work as intended, as it only changes the color brightness via software, and does not change the *backlight* as requested.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution was changing the GRUB settings!
(to change GRUB you must have superuser access)

edit your GRUB by running:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

add **acpi_backlight=vendor** to **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT**, so it should look like something like this (if you don't have additional parameters):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

then you should update your GRUB by this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and after all, you must reboot your system for the changes to take effect:

```
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly because of driver issue. Installed driver and system configuration is not properly connected.

1. Find the driver installed in your computer. search + software update > driver >  additional driver
2. In my case, I found that configuration was set to initialConfiguration which is not configured in system as well. so there is no way, Ubuntu can get configuration. So, we need to change it.

Mostly the path is:

`sudo vim /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf`
or similar in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/*` directory depending on step 1

Then:

Initially File should look like this:

```
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" # See this, configured to InitialConfig
    Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1;" 
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg"
EndSection
```

```
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1;" # This is important
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg"
EndSection
```

Then reboot and cheers!